# How to control / parse an array that sits above HTML header

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Having a hard time parsing the HTML found at.

Response header is:
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 28078

http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1054664

I have tried the following:

Get the html table and parse by row or node or elements. All three work, sort of. The html is awkward and there are random spaces, no ID only class names. parsing is a pain.

I see that above the html there sits this table, in what data format I am not sure. How can I get to this data / parse it?

Put my code below the html, the ignore the bottom portion, I have coded / broke down dozens of different attempts including loading the text/html into xml and work with it.

```
"<!--mod v2-->
<!--ALL INQUIRY TYPE: BXS1PRA3-->
<!--AllInquiryType :: BXS1PRA3
ECBIn :: 
AllBin :: 1054664
AllCount :: 0001
AllBorough :: 
BoilerNumber :: 
OpenObjectionFlag :: 
BiswebReporting :: 
InternalFlag :: 
BoroughKey :: I
StCodeKey :: 
BldgLoKey :: 
JobSubmDate :: 
AllNumbHous :: 
AllStrt :: 
AllBoroughName :: 
AllIsn :: 
PassWorkOrderNumber :: 
PassJobNumber :: 
PassDocNumber :: 
SeqNumber :: 
PPremise60 :: 
PassRecordNumber :: 
RqidPriorToA :: 
RqidPriorToP :: 
RqidPriorToS :: 
RqidItemStatusAll :: 
RqidItemStatusOpen :: 
RqidMultiLineFirst :: 
RqidMultiLineAll :: 
RqidIndex :: 
NotUsed :: 
StartFloorSc52 :: 
JobTypeDesc :: 
PassDeviceNumber :: 
NextIndex :: 
EMPTYPARAMCANBEUSED :: 
AllLicNoCurrent :: 
AllLicTypeCurrent :: 
Empty1 :: 
AllCnNumber :: 
AllCdNumber :: 
ApplNumOcv5 :: 
PageNumber :: 
PfKey :: 
AllEmailAddrCurrent :: 
Empty2 :: 
StartActiveSelect :: 
AllControlNumber :: 
AllStartDate :: 
AllEndDate :: 
AllJobType :: 
AllCommBd :: 
AllViolationType :: 
AllIsn2 :: 
AllTblType :: 
AllBlock :: 
AllLot :: 
AllTblCode :: 
TblBusinessName :: 
AllJAppProfTitle :: 
AllJAppLicNumber :: 
AllMetrixId :: 
InPassword :: 
InUserId :: 
NavFlag :: 
STypeOcv3 :: 
PtTempStatus :: 
PtOtherAuthApproval :: 
PtOtherAuthSig :: 
FillerData :: 
PassTempJobNumber :: 
AllKey1 :: 
AllKey2 :: 
AllFilterLarge :: 
AllFileId :: 
AllMemoType :: 
AllNumOfDataLines :: 
ReadSw :: D
FinFlag :: 
VbLoginId :: 
SustainableFlag :: 
-->
<!--Fin :: 0
ErrorMsg :: 
MoreErrors :: 
MFErrorArray ::  ARRAY[2 * 120]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode]{ }
    [1:ArrayIndex]{ }
MFErrorArray2 ::  ARRAY[3 * 60]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode2]{ }
    [1:Substitution]{ }
    [2:ArrayIndex2]{ }
NotUsed :: 
AllControlNumber :: 07/30/1
Datu :: 8
Pgm :: BXS1PRA3
VlNumbHous :: 2421
NmStrt :: 2 AVENUE
NmBoro :: MANHATTAN
VlBin :: 1054664
VlNumbZip :: 10035
VlTaxBlock :: 01789
VlTaxLot :: 00024
VlCensTract :: 242
VlHlthArea :: 1700
HseLo :: 
HseHi :: 
GlJobType :: 
GlPageN :: 0001
GlRecCountN :: 0000000008
FoilIndicator :: 
GlMax :: 
DebugMsg :: 
BoroughName :: 
NumbHous :: 
Strt :: 
TransactionExecuted :: BXS1PRA3
Lines ::  ARRAY[22 * 40]
[1]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000564806}
    [1:Fd]{12062006}
    [2:Job]{104619478}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A3}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{001}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{R}
    [9:Jobstatus]{PERMIT-ENTIRE}
    [10:Dt]{12112006}
    [11:Applicant]{DEL MAST}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{INSTALLATION OF A SCAFFOLD 16&#039; LONG X 38&#039; HIGH ON THE EXISTING SIDEWALK SH}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{OT}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[2]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000555722}
    [1:Fd]{09212006}
    [2:Job]{104550629}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A2}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{001,002,003,004,005}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{R}
    [9:Jobstatus]{PERMIT-ENTIRE}
    [10:Dt]{09212006}
    [11:Applicant]{Shapiro}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{Filing herewith to make building structurally stable inconjunction with de}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{0060597 PE}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[3]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000520307}
    [1:Fd]{02092006}
    [2:Job]{104294096}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{DM}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{001}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{X}
    [9:Jobstatus]{SIGNED OFF}
    [10:Dt]{02022007}
    [11:Applicant]{JACOBSON}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{1788510 RA}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[4]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000462054}
    [1:Fd]{07192004}
    [2:Job]{103835735}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A3}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{GRD}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{R}
    [9:Jobstatus]{PERMIT-ENTIRE}
    [10:Dt]{08192005}
    [11:Applicant]{SINGH}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{CONSTRUCTION OF 65 LF HEAVY DUTY SIDEWAL K SHED WITH NOSTORAGE  AS PER P}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[5]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000184027}
    [1:Fd]{06121997}
    [2:Job]{101534190}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A3}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{                         001 thru 005}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{R}
    [9:Jobstatus]{PERMIT-ENTIRE}
    [10:Dt]{07011997}
    [11:Applicant]{KO}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{FIRE ESCAPES TO REPLACE EXISTING FIRE BALCONY.}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{0011493 RA}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[6]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000010982}
    [1:Fd]{10041990}
    [2:Job]{100121823}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A2}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{1,  CLR}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{P}
    [9:Jobstatus]{APPROVED}
    [10:Dt]{10121990}
    [11:Applicant]{ESHKAR}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{WORK AT NEW LAUNDROMAT ON FIRST FLOOR. N EW WASHERS, DRYERS, NEW HUNG}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{0018190 RA}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[7]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000010981}
    [1:Fd]{10041990}
    [2:Job]{100121814}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A2}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{1}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{J}
    [9:Jobstatus]{P/E DISAPPROVED}
    [10:Dt]{05091991}
    [11:Applicant]{ESHKAR}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{INSTALL ANSUL SYSTEM AT RESTAURANT. INST ALL SPRINKLERS AT DRYERS AT}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{0018190 RA}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
[8]
    [0:Pra3Isn]{0000006469}
    [1:Fd]{07231990}
    [2:Job]{100079852}
    [3:Ap]{01}
    [4:JobType]{A3}
    [5:Demo]{}
    [6:FlrInjq]{GRD}
    [7:Gas]{}
    [8:Js]{R}
    [9:Jobstatus]{PERMIT-ENTIRE}
    [10:Dt]{05151991}
    [11:Applicant]{JONES}
    [12:Rep]{}
    [13:Jobdes]{ERECT 27 FEET OF SIDEWALK SHED FOR REPAI R OF FACADE. NO CHANGE IN USE}
    [14:JAppLicNumberDisp]{}
    [15:JAuditCodeFlag]{}
    [16:DiagramFlag]{N}
    [17:ZoningDiagramStatus]{N}
    [18:ZoningDiagramRecDate]{}
    [19:DocType]{IF}
    [20:FoundationAppDate]{}
    [21:Bin]{1054664}
-->


<html> 
<head>
    <title>Job Overview</title>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""bsqpm.css"" media=""screen"">
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type""text/css"" href=""print.css"" media=""print"">
    <link rel=""shortcut icon"" href=""/favicon.ico"" type=""image/x-icon"" />
    <script language=""javascript"" src=""bis_lib.js""></script>
    <script language=""javascript"" src=""sorttable.js""></script>
    <script language=""javascript"">
    function $(eln)
    {
        return document.getElementById(eln);
    }
    </script>
        <script language=""javascript"">
    <!--
        function page(loc, ref)
        {
            //Commented out the usagelog creation for Caching on 4-30-15
            //var ce = (document.cookie == null || document.cookie == """") ? ""n"" : ""y"";
            //var u = 'Log/img.gif?m=pg&url='+escape(loc)+'&ref='+escape(ref)+'&ra='+Math.round(Math.random()*100000)+'&ce='+ce;
            //(new Image(1,1)).src = u;
        }

        //onclick=""page('/path/place', document.location);""

                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16591777-1']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();

    //-->
    </script>

</head>


<body bgcolor=""#ffffff"" leftmargin=""0"" topmargin=""0"" marginheight=""0"" marginwidth=""0"" bgproperties=""fixed"">
<center>
    <table border=""0"" cellpadding=""3"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""100%"">  <!--- Start of Header --->
        <tr>
            <td class=""header"" align=""center"" colspan=""3"" width=""100%"">
            <DIV class=""noprint"">
                <table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""100%"">
                    <tr>
                        <td class=""header"">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='bsqpm01.jsp'>BIS Menu</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Applications
                        </td>
                        <td class=""header2"" align=""right"">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=""http://www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/homeowner/homeowner-faqs.page"">FAQs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=""http://www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/about/acronym-glossary.page"">Glossary</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <script language=""javascript"">
                            <!---
                                print_today();
                            //--->
                            </script>
                                <script language=""javascript"">
    <!--
        function page(loc, ref)
        {
            //Commented out the usagelog creation for Caching on 4-30-15
            //var ce = (document.cookie == null || document.cookie == """") ? ""n"" : ""y"";
            //var u = 'Log/img.gif?m=pg&url='+escape(loc)+'&ref='+escape(ref)+'&ra='+Math.round(Math.random()*100000)+'&ce='+ce;
            //(new Image(1,1)).src = u;
        }

        //onclick=""page('/path/place', document.location);""

                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16591777-1']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();

    //-->
    </script>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </DIV>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><a href=""http://www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/index.page""><img src=""./images/doblogo_1.jpg"" alt=""DOB Logo - Link to Homepage"" border=""0""></a></td>  <!--- Cell for DOB Logo --->
            <td align=""right""><a href=""http://www1.nyc.gov/""><img src=""./images/nyclogo.gif"" alt=""NYC.gov Logo - Link to Homepage"" border=""0""></a>
                <br>
                <a href=""https://www.nyc.gov/portal/site/nycgov/menuitem.63099911d804683c09416f1076a09da0/"" onclick=""javascript:page('/ext/signupnews', document.location);"">
                    <img border=""0"" src=""images/clckhere.gif"" onmouseover=""this.src='images/clckhere_over.gif';"" onmouseout=""this.src='images/clckhere.gif';"">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 class=""nychdg"" align=""center""><b>NYC Department of Buildings</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 class=""mainhdg"" align=""center"">Job Overview</td>
        </tr>

    </table>        <!--- End of Header --->


<!---Start Message --->
```

CODE:

```
Sub getAndParse()
    Dim bin As String
        bin = 1054664

    Dim URLOne As String
        URLOne = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=" & bin

    Dim xmlOne As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Set xmlOne = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim htmlOne As Object
        Set htmlOne = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With xmlOne
        .Open "GET", URLOne
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
        .send
    End With

    With xmlOne
        While Not .readyState = 4
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        If .Status = 200 Then
            While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0
                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
            Wend
                htmlOne.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Else
            MsgBox "Connection Unable To Be Made, Try Again"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With


    Debug.Print xmlOne.getAllResponseHeaders
    Stop
    [A1] = xmlOne.responseText

    For Each nde In htmlOne.body.Children
        Debug.Print nde.innerText
    Next nde

    Dim tblRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow

    For Each tblRow In tbl.Rows
        Debug.Print tblRow.innerText
    Next tblRow
End Sub
```

Comment: That's just a plain-text comment hosted on the HTML page.

Comment: how do i grab it? is it possible to parse through parent child? what do the [1] etc signify (if anything)

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of the comment is, or what that format is.  It's not XML for sure.  If you want to parse it you'll need to do it line-by-line.

Comment: @QHarr looks better than the row by row print out that I had been working with. Not familiar with outerHtml property, have a lot to explore re these objects. Thank you +1+1+1

Comment: Glad it worked out ok :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal but this does side-step the difficulties of the middle table formatting by simply copy pasting it. I appreciate you may want the more organised approach of using the "array" info.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object, xmlHttp As Object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    Const URL As String = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1054664"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set html = GetHTMLDoc(URL, xmlHttp)
    With html
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(5)
        Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal URL As String, ByRef xmlHttp As Object) As HTMLDocument
    With xmlHttp
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set GetHTMLDoc = html
End Function
```

---

**References:**

1. HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library